# Is simplicial localization part of a Quillen equivalence between relative categories and simplicial categories?

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, model-categories, simplicial-categories

There are many models for $\infty$-categories. One of them is [relative categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relative+category) – AKA categories with weak equivalences – which have a model structure due to Barwick–Kan. Another one is [simplicial categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+category) with Bergner's structure. It is otherwise known that these two are Quillen equivalent, but the equivalence goes through complete Segal spaces and quasi-categories (see e.g. Bergner's book *The Homotopy Theory of $(\infty,1)$-categories* for a recap).

There is a functor from relative categories to simplicial categories given by [simplicial localizations](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+localization). This is a very naïve question, but is it part of a Quillen equivalence? (Honestly, I expect that the answer is no, otherwise it would probably have been mentioned in the reference books I've read, but you never know...) If not, is it possible to find a direct one between these two model categories?

(I'm aware that the answer to my title taken literally could be "yes, define a model structure on simplicial categories through transfer, and voilà". That's not really what I'm expecting. The model structure on both is fixed.)

Comment: Maybe a more precise way of formulating what you want is whether the simplicial localization induces an equivalence of relative categories (I assume you are not too committed to keep the cofibrations or the fibrations fixed :))

Comment: @DenisNardin Sure, that works too!

Comment: In this case I know that a Quillen equivalence between two model categories induces a Dwyer–Kan equivalence (i.e. an equivalence in Bergner's structure) between the hammock localizations. (First taking the subcategories of fibrant-cofibrant objects.) But I don't  know if it's true for any weak equivalence of relative categories.

Comment: Is there a simplicial localization functor which is adjoint (either left or right)?

Comment: @ValeryIsaev I don't know, is there? That's part of my question.

Comment: Some clarification of exactly what you want is in order. If you really want a Quillen equivalence, then the problem becomes very rigid -- for a start, you need a simplicial localization functor which is part of an adjunction, as Valery Isaev points out. This seems rather unlikely to me (and barring this, you _can't_ just transfer a model structure as claimed in the question statement). If, as suggested by Denis Nardin, all you want is an equivalence of relative categories, then the question is much, much "looser", and likely an affirmative answer falls out of standard model comparison results.

Comment: @TimCampion Let's phrase it this way: if one can prove that there's no Quillen equivalence, then I'd be happy to settle for a weak equivalence of relative categories.